# Save compressed files into s3 and load in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-athena

Hi I am writing some program that will write in some files (with more processes at the time) like:

```
with gzip.open('filename.gz', 'a') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(some dictionary) + '\n')
    f.flush()
```

After writing finishes I upload files with:

```
s3.meta.client(filename, bucket, destination, filename without .gz)
```

Than I want to query data from Athena, after MSCK REPAIR everything seems fine but when I try to select data my rows are empty. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My mistake. I have forgot to add ContentType parameter to 'text/plain'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by first saving bigger chunks of files locally and than gzip them. I repeat the process but with appending to gziped file. Read that it is better to add bigger chunks of text than just line by line

For the upload I used boto3.transfet.upload_file with extra_args={'ContentEncoding': 'gzip', 'ContentType': 'text/plain'}

I forgot to add ContetType first time so the s3 saved them differently and Athena gave me errors that said my JSON is not formatted right.

Answer (score 1):

Athena detects the file compression format with the appropriate file extension.

So if you upload a GZIP file, but remove the '.gz' part (as I would guess from your "s3.meta.client(filename, bucket, destination, filename without .gz)" statement), the SerDe is not able to read the information.

If you rename your files to filename.gz, Athena should be able to read your files.

Comment: I tried that also but then I get error that says my JSON is not formatted properly. I didn't set content_encoding to gzip though so I guess that is the problem. Trying it now

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you break the problem into several parts.

First, **create a single JSON file that is not gzipped**. Store it in Amazon S3, then use Athena to query it.

Once that works, **manually gzip the file** from the command-line (rather than programmatically), put the file in S3 and use Athena to query it.

If that works, **use your code to programmatically gzip it**, and try it again.

If that works with a single file, try it with **multiple files**.

All of the above can be tested with the same command in Athena -- you're simply substituting the source file.

This way, you'll know **which part** of the process is upsetting Athena without compounding the potential causes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have tried to manually gzip file and upload it to s3 bucket, set the content encoding and it worked that way. When I do it programmatically it seems to me that s3 saves files correctly. When I download them and unzip everything looks fine. Loaded data into Athena but after I try to query it I get error that my JSON is not correct.

Comment: Does the JSON file work correct with Athena if it is NOT gzipped?